# R: Make a pivot table based on 3 columns [transpose]

Tags: r

I have this dataframe (df):

```
ID  Type  Order Revenue
1   apples  1    $100
1   oranges 2    $100 
2   grapes  1    $500
2   oranges 2    $500
2   grapes  3    $500
2   grapes  4    $500
```

I want to transpose it to get this dataframe, where the column headers are the "order" column from the original data frame:

```
ID   1       2      3      4     Revenue
1  apples oranges                  $100 
2  grapes oranges grapes grapes    $500
```

I tried `dcast(df, df$ID, df$Order)`

But that doesn't give me what I'm looking for. It gives me the order within the dataframe itself, like this:

```
   ID   1   2   3   4
    1   1   2
    2   1   2   3   4
```

I basically want the "type" to be populated within the dataframe, given a particular ID and order (this combination is unique.)

Thanks so much in advance!!

**EDIT:**
I would like the revenue column to be added while using dcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dcast` takes a `formula` as its second argument.  So, you need to provide that along with the value column that needs to fill up the 'wide' format.  In this case, the `value.var' is 'Type'

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ID~Order, value.var='Type', fill='')
#   ID      1       2      3      4
#1  1 apples oranges              
#2  2 grapes oranges grapes grapes
```

Or you can use `spread` which takes the argument similar to as showed in your post

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, Order, Type, fill='')
```

#### Update

For the updated dataset, change the 'formula'

```
  dcast(dfN, ID+Revenue~Order, value.var='Type', fill='')
  #  ID Revenue      1       2      3      4
  #1  1    $100 apples oranges              
  #2  2    $500 grapes oranges grapes grapes
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Type = c("apples", 
"oranges", "grapes", "oranges", "grapes", "grapes"), Order = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("ID", "Type", "Order"),
 class =  "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get this error: Error: value.var (Type) not found in input.
Therefore, I tried: dcast(df, ID~Order, value.var='df$Type', fill=''); but I get this error: Error in if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { : 
  argument is of length zero

Comment: @user4918087 From the example data you provided, there are three columns, and `Type` is one of them.  I also updated with the data I used.  I noticed that you are not using the same code as I showed. i.e. `value.var='Type'` and not `value.var='df$Type'`

Comment: If I wanted to add another column during dcast, (say revenue column), is that possible? So I have the same revenue repeating for each ID, and I want that to be displayed as another column in the output

Comment: @user4918087 No problem.  You can check more details from `?dcast`, `?spread`